# Node.js app reading cached json value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

I have recently started making a node.js app and have gotten to a point at which I need to read a value of a JSON that has just been updated, but not successfully, I have tried using the 'sleep' module to stop threads for a small delay but still no luck.

I haven't been using node.js for very long either, for only about 5 months.

```
var obj;

let sData = ('./session-data/data.json');
var contents = fs.readFile(sData, 'utf8', function(err, data){
  if (err) throw err;
  obj = JSON.parse(data);
});

// Below is getting input text from an inquirer question & logging it to the json but when console.log 'ed it outputs the last value from the key in the json
fs.writeFile('./session-data/data.json', `{\n "video": "` + answers.input + `"\n}`, function(err){
  if(err){
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Video: ' + obj.video)
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no code, no error and no expected result it's very hard to answer with any specific solution. All I can say after reading the question is that whatever your problem is, you shouldn't use the sleep module for that. From the documentation: "These calls will block execution of all JavaScript by halting Node.js' event loop!" You never want to do that with things that you describe.

Presumably your "JSON" (by which you probably mean an object, not JSON, but I'm guessing here) is updated by some operation, inside of some callback or event handler or as a result of a promise resolution etc. Instead of introducing specific delays you should listen for a relevant event, add a promise resolution handler, add a callback etc. where you could know when the value is changed and needs to be acted upon.

Introducing random delays will never help you with that, and introducing delays that block the entire event loop will only cause trouble.